# Object moves slightly past a point that it is supposed to stop (Unity 2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, operators

I am trying to get an object in Unity2D to stop at a specific point. The object will stop but the position will still be greater than/less than that of what I need it to be for my program. I need the object to stop at a patrol point and a boolean to be false if the object has gone past the patrol point. My code is as follows:

```
 private void FixedUpdate()
{
    enemyLocation = GetComponent<Transform>();

    Debug.Log("Enemy Location: " + enemyLocation.position.x + "Patrol Location: " + patrolList[1].position.x);
    if (enemyLocation.position.x >= patrolList[0].position.x && enemyLocation.position.x <= patrolList[1].position.x)
    {
        inPatrolRange = true;
    }
    else
    {
        inPatrolRange = false;
    }

    // Used for randomness
    gameTime = Time.time;

    if (inPatrolRange)
    {
        Patrol();
    }

}
```

The ouput to the console is as follows:

Enemy Location: 1.527214Patrol Location: 1.521

For my script to work correctly, I need enemyLocation to be equal to the patrol location. What can I do to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In order your Transform `enemyLocation` stay in bounds of your patrols, you can use [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html):

```
float min = patrolList[0].position.x;
float max = patrolList[1].position.x;
float x = Mathf.Clamp(enemyLocation.position.x, min, max);
enemyLocation.position = new Vector3(x, enemyLocation.position.y);
```

If you don't need to do some stuff with Physics, use `Update` instead of `FixedUpdate`. You should also consider moving the `GetComponent` out of the Update loop for optimization.

Comment: When I implement this code, my object seizes to move. How does setting the enemy's position equal to the clamp keep it inside of the clamp? Also, I am using rigidbody.velocity to move the object.